# set up User email verification after Signup in wordpress theme

Tags: themes, email, email-verification, signup

I want to set up User email verification after Signup on my site [www.availabler.com](http://www.availabler.com) in wordpress theme. tried multiple methods but no luck.
Please assist.

Comment: What were those multiple methods you tried? it would help us if you tell them to use so we can avoid suggesting them again to you.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. We tried custom code, plugins and third-party api.